# how to pass to a php function using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How do I call the `insertScore` so that I can pass the values. I think it would look like this. `insertScore($name,$num_guess)` but where do I put it?

This is the **PHP part**:

```
function insertScore($name,$num_guess){
opendb();
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbconn'],"INSERT INTO game VALUES (0,'$name',$num_guess");
closedb();}
```

and this is the **Ajax part:**

```
$("#user .button ul li #submit").click( function(){
$.post("utilities.php",{
    user_name:$("#user_name").val(),
    num_guess:$("#num_guess").val()
  },
  function(response){
      $("#msgbox #msg").html("Score Submitted");
      $("#msgbox").slideUp().slideDown("slow");
  }
);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `utilities.php` -

```
insertScore($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['num_guess']);
```

Basically, you can access all the values which were sent through post request using `$_POST` superglobal.

But don't send this data directly to your database, as it may contain harmful [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should sanitize the input or use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: it's saying undefined index.

Comment: it said "Array()". What does that mean?

Comment: It means an empty array is sent. Do you even have input field with id `"user_name"`?

Comment: I have an input field with. It's already saying undefined variable user_name and num_guess when i put insertScore($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['num_guess']); in the utilities

Answer (score 0):

POST parameters can be accessed using PHPs `$_POST` superglobal. You could do this in `utilities.php`:

```
insertScore($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['num_guess']);
```

However, that function is prone to SQL injections. You should make sure to escape properly or use prepared statements! I definitely recommend using PHPs builtin database acesss [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). The `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions are generally considered bad practice.

Comment: it returns undefined user_name and num_guess

Comment: @Dale - Is that function defined in `utilities.php`?

Comment: I put insertScore($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['num_guess']); after defining the function but it says undefined variable user_name and num_guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you name your php file *utilities.php* and access it, say you have your insertScore function definition. You want to add a call to that function in the end of the file, and inside the function, access the [$_POST variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). You'd be accessing the data you sent from the ajax call in your $.post at JS side.

Comment: When you send a request to your utilities.php file it's "executed". Which means if you have only your function declaration, it'll never get called. So what you do is call your function right after you defined it. Inside, you can pick up the values you sent from the client, as they are inside the $_POST array.

Comment: But why is it still saying undefined variable in user_name and num_guess?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your php code is not a valid code because of malconstructing `mysql query`.

then the php code you are asking about must exist after closing the function `}` in your php file

and it will be like this : `internetScore($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['num_guess']);`

Please try this and tell me if this solve your problem :)

Please apply what i will say and tell me if this work :)

Update your jquery code like this :

```
$("#user .button ul li #submit").click( function(){
$.post("utilities.php",{
'user_name':$("#user_name").val(),
'num_guess':$("#num_guess").val()
},
function(response){
  $("#msgbox #msg").html("Score Submitted");
  $("#msgbox").slideUp().slideDown("slow");
}
);
return false;
});
```

the only modification is the quote around your posted variable please let me know if this work :)

Comment: Hello @Dale : you see it is not working ? first of all try to alert($("#user_name").val());
before thre returne false in your javascript code.
then see if it alerts you with the user name or it will alert an undefined warning :)

Comment: why is it saying undefined variable when  I put internetScore($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['num_guess']); in my utilities after defining the function?

Comment: Hello @Dale : This warning means that the $_POST array passed to your "utitlities.php" doesn't contain any key with the name 'user_name' nether 'num_guess' and this maybe is the result of the jquery error of passing variables and as i told you try put quotes around your variable in your jquery then tell me if this works :)

Comment: it's still says undefined variable.

Comment: I tried replacing post with request and it worked but it broke the ajax part so I place post again ang it says undefined.

Comment: Hello @Dale : can you please give me exactly what is the error you have ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: user_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\Guess V2\utilities.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined index: num_guess in C:\xampp\htdocs\Guess V2\utilities.php on line 28

Comment: Hello @Dale : Can you please post exactly your html and jquery code so i can know where did you get the warning inside your display page because as i see that your jquery doesn't load the result of jquery post in any side of your page .... :)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#user #msgbox").hide();
  $("#user .button ul li #submit").click( function(){
  $.request("utilities.php",{
    'user_name':$("#user_name").val(),
    'num_guess':$("#num_guess").val(),
  },
  function(response){
    $("#msgbox #msg").html("Score Submitted");
    $("#msgbox").slideUp().slideDown("slow");
  });
    return false;
  });
});

Comment: <div class="button">
      <ul>
   <li><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/></li>
   <li><input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Play Again"/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </form>
   </div>

Comment: Hi @Dale : as i can see that you have not posted your complete code as i cannot see how you begin your form tag and where is the text input element exists in your code please edit your post and insert the full code i want to give you my maximum help but i don't have a clear image for what is happing so i am waiting your editing of your post :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723550/undefined-variable-user-name-and-num-guess-using-post-method I posted the code here

Comment: Hey @Dale please try to modify your button from submit type to button type :)

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a `.php` web page or if you send an ajax `POST` or `GET` request to a `.php` page,  then when that `PHP` file runs, it has access to two important variables [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php). You can access these variables at any point in your `PHP` file.

What you have done is define a function `insertScore` that takes two parameters, but is never called. At some point in the main execution of your file `utilities.php` you need to call `insertScore` with the correct parameters.

The [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable is an associative array that gives you access to the data you are sending over AJAX (and indeed other things can sand that data to your PHP file). To access user_name and num_guess that the AJAX request sends, you can use the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable like so:

```
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$num_guess = $_POST['num_guess'];
```

And you can use these variables, or the array directly. Something you must be very careful of is malicious people. If you were to use the input here directly in your MySQL query, then you are open to an SQL Injection attack (which are very common) which will completely compromise your database server, so you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on your data beforehand. So your code should look like so:

```
function insertScore($name,$num_guess){
  opendb();
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['dbconn'],$name);
  $num_guess = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['dbconn'],$num_guess);
  $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['dbconn'],"INSERT INTO game VALUES (0,'$name',$num_guess");
  closedb();
}
```

Then somewhere else in your file, you should place this:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['num_guess'])){
  insertScore($_POST['user_name'],$_POST['num_guess']);
}
```

I would recommend reading up further on database / website security, there are lots of things that can catch you out and leave you vulnerable. This is still not the best way to go about writing this, but it will get you started. I suggest looking at [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to read into this further.